# Web access is extremely slow

Tags: performance, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-web-access

I have TFS 2015 installed on one of the company's servers. I try to access TFS using web access and it is extremely slow, it takes more than 5 minutes for a page to load and sometimes even longer. If I restart the server, TFS becomes a little bit faster (a page would need only a minute or so to load), but soon it becomes slower.

The server itself is okay. The CPU and memory are not even fully utilized (~20% - ~40% is utilized).

Other applications that are installed on the server are working fine, so it's just TFS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: just you or is it the same for eveyone else too? is there anything in the event log on the on TFS AT?

Comment: it's for everyone. I couldn't find any error related to TFS performance in the event log

Comment: no timeouts? is it the same if you rdp onto the box and work locally?

Comment: Sometimes it servers the page after a long time and sometimes it shows an error. But I forgot what was the error

Comment: Go look at the system requirements documentation and ensure that the infrastructure meets or exceeds them. You're looking at the app tier, which is pretty lightweight. You're likely experiencing issues on the data tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log in the application tier machine to try to access the web access to see whether you can see the same behavior.
2. Check the network connection between the application tier machine and data tier machine if you set up TFS in a multiple server configuration. You may try to turn off the firewall and anti-virus software on the machines.
3. Clean the cache folder on the application tier, usually the folder locates in: `C:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache`
4. Check the [Requirements and compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements), to see whether your TFS set up on a appropriate environment.
5. If the items above is not helpful. You may need to consider [move your TFS to another hardware](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-clone-hardware).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The performance problem is visible whether I access the TFS from my PC or directly from the server. I couldn't find the TFSData folder (or a similar folder) should it be inside the installation folder?

Comment: You can check the cache folder in the TFS Administration Console on the application tier machine.

Comment: I checked the chache folder but I don't think it's the cause of the problem because it's very small in size (~7MB)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Although your answer didn't help me, but I'll mark it as an answer because it contained helpful information that might be of a help to some others

Comment: Did you validate the speed and connectivity of the data tier?